# Free up a Map memory space used on over multiple steps

Tags: java, collections, spring-batch

I'm using spring batch with multiple steps, as we go along on execution i see that the memory occupation is grown, as i'm using Map structures to store data reads from multiple csv files . I'm using these data to dodo some transformation records.

So my question is what is the most/proper way to free memory occupation.

```
@Bean
    public Job importParameterJob() {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importParameterJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start((step1()))
                .next((step2))
                .next((step3))
                .next((step4))
                .next((step5))
                .next(finalStep())
                .build();
    }
```

Let's take an example here , my step 2 is using a list to store alla reds record from csv file to Map (List), more precisely the Item processor for the step 2 store all records on Map List

```
public class Step2ItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Step2FileRow, Step2FileRow> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Step2ItemProcessor.class);

    private Map<Long , Step2FileRow> step2FileRowMap;

    public Step2ItemProcessor() {
        step2FileRowMap = new HashMap<Long , Step2FileRow>();
        log.info("Step2 ItemProcessor a été crée avec une Map pour charger tous les Step2s");
    }

    @Override
    public Step2FileRow process(final Step2FileRow Step2FileRow) throws Exception {
        step2FileRowMap.put(Step2FileRow.getId(), Step2FileRow);
        log.info("Le Step2 ID :" + Step2FileRow.getId() +" a été ajouté dans la liste des Step2s en memoire Map");
        return null;
    }

    public Map<Long , Step2FileRow> getstep2FileRowMap() {
        return step2FileRowMap;
    }
}
```

for some reason i need to use this Map within other steps, 
so if the needed list is used to dodo what i have todo, all these records still on memory after the work is done, my question haw can i  free this ItemProcessor with his list.
did i should use a taklet and inject this ItemProcessor and then put his list to null ? or use the clear() method to free record from Map

```
@Autowired
    private Step2ItemProcessor listObject;
```

Comment: Let `Step2ItemProcessor` implements `JobExecutionListener` and `clear()` your map in `afterJob()`

Comment: Thank you for your kind help .i can't because i still using the Map on step 3 and step 4 (as i mentioned the Map store some record that i need to refer to when performing some stuff) , in fact from step 5 i'm not referring to this Map and i can/should delete this Map. this why i'm thinking of tasklet

Comment: Let `step5` implements `StepExecutionListener`

Comment: so it will be something like this @Override
 public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
  listObject.getMap.clear()
  return null;
 }

Comment: or - better - `beforeStep()`

Comment: Thak you Very much @Luca

Comment: I'd implement the `ItemStream` interface...

Comment: @MichaelMinella could you give me some more information about

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for what you want to do:

1. Define the components as step scoped - This will allow each step to get it's own instance and the previous ones be made available for garbage collection.
2. Implement the `ItemStream` interface on your component - The `ItemStream` interface is intended to be implemented by any stateful Spring Batch component.  It provides three methods called by the framework:

   - `ItemStream#open(ExecutionContext context)` - This method is called before processing of data begins to allow for a component to open any required resources and to reset any state that may have previously been stored in a previous run.
   - `ItemStream#update(ExecutionContext context)` - This method is called periodically through the execution of a step allowing the component to save off any state in case of a failure.
   - `ItemStream#close()` - This method is provided to clean up any resources after the completion of processing.

In the `ItemStream` option, you'd re-initialize each `Map` in the `ItemStream#open` and potentially clean it up in `ItemStream#close`.

You can read more about the step scoped components here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/step.html#step-scope
You can read more about the `ItemStream` interface here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemStream.html

Comment: first i would like to thank you for your kind help and cooperation .
As i'm using a Map to store all records read from the step one and as i mentioned before this Map will be used within the step 2 and step 3 and then from step 4 there is no need to use it, i can't see your approach acceptable here : **recording to 1** this approach is not applicable as i'm always refer to this list on several steps.
**recording to 2**  this approach has an additional cost, on every step i will recreate the Map and destroy it multiple times

Comment: If you need the map to be stored over multiple steps, you'll need to use a listener to create and clean it up.

Comment: yes, i confirm that as @Luca Basso Ricci comments, Thank you you again

Comment: You may want to update your original question to be more clear.  It doesn't state that the maps must be used over multiple steps.